# How to insert js to electron app like chrome content scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

for ex, here is my app, I open evernote web, I hope insert js to add shortcut for evernote web, how to do it?

```
var el = require("electron")

var app = el.app
var Win = el.BrowserWindow
app.on("ready", function () {
  var win = new Win
  win.loadURL("https://sandbox.evernote.com/Home.action?")
  win.focus()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't find the way to do this, so I should use electron webview load evernote web and inject js